# How to create a list of every items purchased by client X?

Tags: python, pandas, list, pivot-table, recommendation-engine

**How can I create a list of every item purchased by the client ID that I specify?**

This question is part of the recommendation system I am building.

**My dataframe** has 3 columns ['ClientID'],['Products'],['Ratings']

*(A 'Rating' different than NaN represent an product purchased)*

**So far I have wrote this code:**

First, I created a pivot table with ['ClientID'] on the vertical index and ['Products'] on the horizontal index and ['Ratings'] as the values.

```
piv = datacf1.pivot_table(index=['ClientID'], columns=['Products'], values=['Ratings'])
```

```
#Drop all columns containing only zeros, representing users who did not rate/purchased
piv.fillna(0, inplace=True)
piv = piv.T
piv = piv.loc[:, (piv != 0).any(axis=0)]
```

The following code uses the pivot table to get the list of purchased items by client X

```
#Create a list of every products traded by user X
purchased = piv.T[piv.loc[5039595.0,:]>0].index.tolist()
purchased
```

`5039595` is the ['ClientID'] for which I want to create my list of items purchased and I would like to apply a different ['ClientID'] on demand.

I get an error when running the code to create the list.

**Why I believe the 'create a list' code gives me an error:**
I believe this code reads the vertical index as ['0','1','2','3',...] so it expects to find the column '5039595', however as said previously the vertical index represents the ['ClientID'] which are random.

Here is a snapshot of the vertical index ['ClientID'] of the pivot table:

[image]

How can I fix my code to look for the Client X that I want to create the list for?

Or is there another way to do it? Perhaps with my original dataset with 3 columns ['ClientID'],['Products'],['Ratings']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to select all the rows containing purchases for a given customer then take all the unique product values from those rows. It would look something like this:

```
desired_rows = (data["ClientID"].isin([client_id]) & data[Ratings].notnull())
product_list = data.loc[desired_rows, "Products"].unique().tolist()
print(product_list)
```

Comment: Beautifully executed! Thank you! You just added '&' twice, if you want to edit your answer.

Comment: Thank you! I'll fix that. I wish Boolean operators where consistent across languages but such is life.
Glad you found it hopeful.